# How can I traverse different parts of data structure one after the other?

Tags: haskell, traversal, haskell-lens

In `Control.Lens.Traversal` the `beside` function traverses both parts of a `Bitraversable`. The example given is

```
>>> ("hello",["world","!!!"])^..beside id traverse
["hello","world","!!!"]
```

Can I write a more explicit version of `beside` (let's call it `bothParts`) that instead of a `Bitraversable` constraint takes two `Traversal`s? I imagine it to be used like so:

```
>>> ("hello",["world","!!!"])^..bothParts _1 _2 id traverse
["hello","world","!!!"]
```

Does this already exist? Is this too unsafe to be sanely used? Thank you!

Edit:

Or perhaps something like:

```
>>> ("hello",["world","!!!"])^..bothParts _1 (_2.traverse)
["hello","world","!!!"]
```

Comment: I think that `bothParts l1 l2` won't always be a valid `Traversal`. Consider `bothParts _1 _1` (or any other case when `l1` and `l2` overlap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combinator you want is supposed to use 2 `Traversal`s simultaneously. But that kind of combinator breaks `Traversal` laws in general, in particular the "no duplication" law: a `Traversal` should traverse each element only once.

Here's an example of what you probably don't want:

```
>>> (1, 2) ^.. bothParts _1 _1
[1, 1]
```

To be more precise, I'd like to cite [`Traversal` documentation from `lens` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html):

> The laws for a `Traversal t` follow from the laws for `Traversable` as stated in ["The Essence of the Iterator Pattern"](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/iterator.pdf).

```
t pure ≡ pure
fmap (t f) . t g ≡ getCompose . t (Compose . fmap f . g)
```

> One consequence of this requirement is that a `Traversal` needs to leave the same number of elements as a candidate for subsequent `Traversal` that it started with. Another testament to the strength of these laws is that the caveat expressed in section 5.5 of the "Essence of the Iterator Pattern" about exotic `Traversable` instances that traverse the same entry multiple times was actually already ruled out by the second law in that same paper!

Comment: Ok, yes, thank you, but if I promise to always traverse different subparts, how would I write such a function?

Comment: @phischu in your question you only use `Traversal`s as `Fold`s, so perhaps it would suffice for you to use [`ReifiedFold`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-Reified.html#t:ReifiedFold) to compose different `Fold`s, e.g.: `("hello",["world","!!!"])^..runFold (Fold _1 <|> Fold (_2.traverse))`

Comment: @phischu would update your question to include desired "setter" example then?